# Converted PowerBuilder to ASP.Net browsing Errors

Tags: asp.net, web, iis-6, web-config, machine.config

I had a powerbuilder application which i converted to web application in the format of ASP.Net (aspx) files.

after deploying and publishing the converted web application (copy it and add ASP.Net and network Service AND IUser permissions to enable users to access it) in IIS V6.0 over Windows server 2003 and The ASP.Net version is 2.0

The error messages I get when I browse default.aspx web page are as the following:-

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error

Description:

An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details:

To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Notes:

The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Another error message appears on the server is:-

Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error

```
<roleManager enabled="true">
<membership>
</roleManager>
```

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Problem is solved. It happened due to configuration files errors. when the process is retried using the proper steps it works fine.**